# How to add custom html to existing widget screen in Odoo 12

Tags: javascript, html, odoo

I've stuck 3 days ago. I'm trying to print order items. What I want is that when I click Order button it add a custom html code to a div that has class 'order-print'.

I used odoo 12 and have problem with javascript. I have tried some code but it doesn't work.

I used the following code and it doesn't set html to '.print-order'.

```
new screens.ProductScreenWidget(this).print_order(r);
```

In multiprint.js:

```
function send_printing_job(){
    if(self.receipt_queue.length > 0){
                var r = self.receipt_queue.shift();
                var options = {shadow: true, timeout: 5000};
                //console.log(r);
                printReceipt(r);
                //self.connection.rpc('/hw_proxy/print_xml_receipt', {receipt: r}, options)
                //    .then(function(){
                //        send_printing_job();
                //    },function(error, event){
                //        self.receipt_queue.unshift(r);
                //        console.log('There was an error while trying to print the order:');
                //        console.log(error);
                //    });
            }
        }
        function printReceipt(r){
            //ProductScreenWidget.render_receipt(r);
            //screens.products.render_order_print(r);

            new screens.ProductScreenWidget(this).print_order(r);
            window.print();
        }
```

In multiprint.js

```
var ProductScreenWidget = ScreenWidget.extend({
    template:'ProductScreenWidget',
...
print_order: function(r){
        console.log(r);
        this.$('order-print').html(r);
    },
```

In pos.xml:

```
<t t-name="ProductScreenWidget">
...
<div class="order-print"></div>
...
```

I can make console.log working but It doesn't set html to existing element class 'order-print'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by replacing the code *new screens.ProductScreenWidget(this).print_order(r);* with the following code:

```
screens.ProductScreenWidget.prototype.print_order(r);
```